# Formula for calculating x2 and y2 of a line that behaves like a clock hand?

Tags: circles

In the image below, the diameter of the circle is 100, and x1=50 and y1=50 for the line's starting point in the middle.

[image]

I'd like to be able to draw the line so that it is pointing at different parts of the outer circle, similar to a clock hand. Meaning I need a formula for calculating the line's x2 and y2.

What is the equation to calculate x2 and y2?

Comment: Please dont keep answers unaccepted(A bad habit inculcated by many members of the site). If you do, please consider to leave a comment stating the reason..

Answer (score 1):

For the minute hand

Total $360^0$ divide into $60$ equal parts$\implies$ each minute's gap $=6^0=\theta_m$ and each minute$= 60 $ seconds $\implies$ each second$=0.1^0=\theta _s$.

So if you want your minute hand to move with every second(height of exactness!! rarely seen in actual clocks!) and taking $(0,0)$ to be $(x_1,y_1)$, your required formula $$x_2=50\sin(\theta)\ ;\ y_2=50\cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta $is calculated as $\theta =$*time in minutes*$\times 6^0+$*time in seconds*$\times 0.1^0$